# Japanese input with AZERTY on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, input-languages, ime, japanese

I'm French, I've a French keyboard.

I look on the web many things, I found [a tool I downloaded](http://www.declan-software.com/japanese_ime/), to write japanese on computer. I have Windows 7. When I use it, if I click on the "a" my keyboard, it gives me a "q". Well it gives me the letter of the English keyboard. And as I think now this tool is only for UK/UK keyboard.

I also found [that](http://www.lexilogos.com/clavier/nihongo_hiragana.htm) which is very useful but I'd like to know if there is a way to the same like this tool but have the possibility to click only on my keyboard without to connect me on this website. If I want to write directly in google tab for example or directly in a word sheet.

Can you help me ? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because we've decided to keep this site focused on the Japanese language itself, so we aren't taking questions about software *related to* the Japanese language at this time.

Comment: @snailplane what a very intelligent thing ... you can learn Japanese but not write it !!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=japanese+input+method

Comment: I will do thanks. It just looks awkward to do that. It's like to make a cake but have not the possibilty to heat it.

Comment: Windows thinks you need a Japanese keyboard layout to activate the IME (which is where your problem comes from). OS X and *nix have no such restriction.

Comment: Oh, maybe https://bluebluewave.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/japanese-input-with-azerty-in-windows-7/